# Excel VBA Subscript Out Of Range on 00:00 Split

Tags: excel, vba

I am looping through a table in Excel with VBA to split the value into the next column. The table looks like this.

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
| Interval Start Date | Interval Start Time |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2019-07-01 04:00    |                     |
| 2019-07-01 05:00    |                     |
| 2019-07-01 05:00    |                     |
| 2019-07-01 05:00    |                     |
| 2019-07-01 06:00    |                     |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

The first column is A the second is B.
I am using this code that I have written/acquired.

```
Sub SplitCells()
    Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row).Copy Destination:=Range("B2")
    Dim rLastRow As Range
    Dim row As Integer
    Set ws = Sheets("Monthly Queue activity by hour-")
    row = 2
    Set rLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)
    rLastRow = rLastRow - 1

    Dim TestArray As Variant
    With ws
        Do
            TestArray = Split(CStr(.Cells(row, 1).Value))
            .Cells(row, 2) = TestArray(1)
            row = row + 1
        Loop Until row = rLastRow
    End With
End Sub
```

It will give me the Subscript Out Of Range if the timestamp I am splitting out is 00:00. I have tried searching and I can't seem to track down how to fix this.

I remove the entries with the 00:00 timestamp and it works, except I still get the Out Of Range when it reaches the end.

Comment: You could use `.Text` instead of `.Value` to retrieve what is displayed as formatted instead, but it will be slower.

Comment: @braX well changing that fixed the 00:00 issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since rLastRow is a range you need to call the `.row` property to end the Loop. This with the `.Text` suggestion should do the trick.

```
Sub SplitCells()
Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row).Copy Destination:=Range("B2")
Dim rLastRow As Range
Dim row As Integer
Set ws = Sheets("Monthly Queue activity by hour-")
row = 2
Set rLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)
rLastRow = rLastRow - 1

Dim TestArray As Variant
With ws
    Do
        TestArray = Split(CStr(.Cells(row, 1).Text))
        .Cells(row, 2) = TestArray(1)
        row = row + 1
    Loop Until row = rLastRow.row + 1
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I have been staring at this for far to long.

Comment: @Unfundednut I'd recommend explicitly specifying a `Delimiter` argument for the `Split` function.